# Using a Japanese Apple Magic Keyboard on 22.04 and 18.04 and would like for it to work on either as it does for hiragana and katakana on Windows 11

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

This new keyboard works perfectly for hiragana and katakana input on Windows 11; and I would like to get it working similarly on any available version of Ubuntu (I curranty have three Ubuntu boxes, running 18.04, 22.04, and 23 respectively). I have tried several things but the layout never matches the Apple Magic keyboard layout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Japanese-layout Apple Magic keyboard on Ubuntu 18.04 running on a 2007 iMac and not getting the correct mapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479683/japanese-layout-apple-magic-keyboard-on-ubuntu-18-04-running-on-a-2007-imac-and)

Comment: You must describe what you tied and what didn't work. Take screenshots. Explain it in a clear state. Do you speak Japanese? Has Your machine a Japanese language and input method installed? You can write questions in Japanese if you want.